# Windows Form Picture Upload Error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am writing a simple windows form application in which i need to give user facility to upload picture from PC, after that i need to show that picture in PictureBox control.
When i browse picture and press Open button it shows Error dialog box with following content:
**"Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
The path is not of a legal form"**
Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Chosen_File = "";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectpic.ShowDialog();
        selectpic.Title = "Browse Employee Picture!";
        selectpic.InitialDirectory = "System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)";
        selectpic.FileName = "";
        selectpic.Filter = "JPEG Images|*.jpg|GIF Images|*.gif|BITMAPS|*.bmp";
        Chosen_File = selectpic.FileName;
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Chosen_File);
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by putting all OpenFileDialog settings before calling the method ShowDialog!

Answer (score 1):

**Anoter thing : No** need for quotations "

```
selectpic.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```